# Fetching records and nested relations

Tags: ember.js

I have a route in my app ([repo](https://github.com/SimonBo/mini_booking_ember)) where i fetch *bookings* belonging to a user, I also include rentals and rentals.rental-ratings in the request. Now, a rental (which belongsTo a Booking) hasMany rentalRatings, and rentalRatings belongsTo Users. In the template I have a component that accepts booking and a rentalRating as arguements. How can I get a rating that belongsTo the booking and the currentUser?

Bookings route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  sessionAccount: Ember.inject.service(),

  model() {
    const currentUser = this.get('sessionAccount.currentUser');

    return this.get('store').query('booking', {
      filter: {
        'user_id': currentUser.id
      },
      include: 'rental,rental.rental-ratings'
    });
  }
});
```

Bookings template:

```
<h1>Your bookings</h1>
{{#each model as |booking|}}
  {{booking-card booking=booking rating="??? what goes here???"}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this, is to use the [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#filter-by).

Move the `sessionAccount` service into the controller. In your template you can just use the `filter-by` helper:

```
{{#each model as |booking|}}
  {{booking-card booking=booking rating=(get (filter-by "user" sessionAccount.user booking.rental.rentalRatings) "firstObject")}}
{{/each}}
```